# Creating (N) directories in a specific path in a loop stopping abruptly

Tags: c#, wpf, system.io.file, system.io.directory

I am attempting to create 10,000 folders in a specific directory.
I have an algorithm for creating a random names for each folder.

The issue I am having is when I run this code, It stops with creating about 21 directories. The `MessageBox.Show()` is debug, however, it never pops up.

`this.WorkingDir` is a string property that looks like this.

`"C:\\Users\\Reapism\\Desktop\\Yo\\"`

```
        DirectoryInfo directoryInfo;
        string dirName; // directory name
        const int dirNameLength = 15;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            dirName = GetRandomString(dirNameLength); // generates "unique name"
            try {
                directoryInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(this.WorkingDir + dirName);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                MessageBox.Show($"{i} {dirName} failed. {e.ToString()}");
            }
        }

        // Inserting a breakpoint here yields 21 directories

        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(this.WorkingDir);
        DirectoryInfo[] directories = d.GetDirectories($"*");

        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in directories) {
            try {
                Directory.Delete(dir.FullName);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException($"Error deleting the directory!" + e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

The **interesting** thing is when I use the Debugger, and step through each iteration of the for loop in creating the directories, it goes further than ***21*** directories, and likely goes all the way to 10k. This would lead me to believe there is a **limit** to creating directories in a certain number of time.

Whats troubling is that no exception is thrown, the loop just discontinues.

Does this have to do with the CPU working quicker than the Disk can report or write a new Folder? If so, how can I get around this? This function is a timed function and using a `Thread.Sleep(50)` for example cannot be used.

Comment: Have you tried to put `dirName` e.g. the  to the `Dictionary<string, string>` (without creating a directory) just to see all entries being created.

Comment: I have no problems with adding 10000 files. Advice - use `Path.Combine` to create a directory name.

Comment: @Rekshino Advice taken!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function GetRandomString generates non unique names, because you create new Random every times. You can use private class member Random which been created one times with class instance. I wrote sample counting unique names.

```
string[] dirNames = new string[10000];

for (i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    dirNames[i] = GetRandomString(dirNameLength); // generates "unique name";

foreach (var dr in dirNames.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => new { Name = x.Key, Count = x.Count() }).Where(x => x.Count > 1))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{dr.Count} {dr.Name}");
}
```

Try this. Аnd don't forget that filenames are case insensitive, so you should use only 36 characters, not 62.

```
private static readonly char[] charList = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".ToCharArray();
private static readonly Random _random = new Random();

private static string GetRandomString(int length)
{
    if (length < 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Length must be greater than 0!");

    return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(charList, length).Select(s => s[_random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Oh right, I am seeding the new Random instance with the same value since its happening so fast... Well done. Great point on the case insensitivity about directory and file names.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your function GetRandomString throws an exception when executes real-time. Put it into try block and check. I tryed to create 10000 folders with names 1,2,3 ...10000 and I have created all.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(WorkingDir, $"{i}"));
    }
```

Comment: This is correct. I replaced the folder creation with using the loop control index and it worked. However, I do want to use the random string if possible. I updated the post to include this.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the update for `GetRandomString()`...

When you create a new instance of `Random` without passing it a seed, the [default constructor](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,52) will seed the new instance from `Environment.TickCount` - the time in milliseconds since the computer was started.  Since this has a resolution of 1ms your code is most likely creating a lot of `Random` instances with the same seed value.  This means that the method will return the same values every time until `Environment.TickCount` rolls over to the next value.

To solve this you should use a single `Random` instance and use that in all of the calls.  Something like this should work:

```
private Random _rnd = null;

private string GetRandomString(int length) 
{
    if (_rnd == null)
        _rnd = new Random();

    if (length < 1) 
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Length must be greater than 0!");

    var sb = new StringBuilder(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        sb.Append(charList[_rnd.Next(charList.Length)]);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

It does essentially the same as what you already have, but only creates a single `Random` instance.  And avoids all that nasty string composition you have going on, so it'll be a tiny bit faster and more memory-friendly.

Another method, if you don't care about the actual names, would be to use `Guid.NewGuid()` to create guaranteed-unique values.

Comment: Well done, creating a single instance does solve it. I forget that initializing the random classes so fast, you will give it the same seed. Looking into Guid might be worth it. Also yes, using the `StringBuilder` would be less costlier in essence. Well done.